# How to customize a Listview at desired row positions?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to customize some rows in my `Listview`. I have used a `BaseAdapter`. I have a overriden getview method in my BaseAdapter class. I just want to know how to customize only one row in the Listview at a particular position. For example, set the textview in position 2 of the listview to sometext i.e viewholder.textview.settext("hii") at position 2.

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments to `getView()` is the position. Just check if the position is the value you want.

```
private int positionThatSaysHi = -1; // not zero, or else first item will have Hi

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    if (position == positionThatSaysHi) {
        // custom
    } else {
        // regular
    }
}

public void setPositionThatSaysHi(int position) {
    if (positionThatSaysHi != position) {
        positionThatSaysHi = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set it at that position only?

Comment: Can you tell me how can we store the position of the previous row on which the textview was already set.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's your adapter class, you can add a method to set the position you want to be custom.

Comment: k..I will explain. If I keep on setting the textviews on clicking the rows the textviews will set at the appropriate positions to hii, but I want at a time only the clicked row to have the value hii and I want all the previously clicked textviews to set back to their default value

Comment: After you set the position that says "Hi", call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will make the ListView obtain views again from the adapter. See my edit.